# How to use Redux with React

Tags: reactjs, redux

What I Just want to fetch data from api and show it at frontend. I am using Redux to call the api using it's **ACTIONS and REDUCERS**. In Reducers i take the intialstate as empty array.When API is successfully called, I am updating store state.Below is the practical which can help to understand concept easily.

**store.js**

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducer from './reducers/reducer';

let store = createStore(reducer)
export default store
```

**actions.js**

```
import { 
 FETCH_IMAGES_SUCCESS
} from './actionTypes'

export function fetchImages() {
  return dispatch => {
   return fetch("https://api.com/data")
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(json => {
     dispatch(fetchImagesSuccess(json.posts));
    return json.posts;
   })
  };
}

export const fetchImagesSuccess = images => ({
  type: FETCH_IMAGES_SUCCESS,
  payload: { images }
});
```

**reducer.js**

```
import {
 FETCH_IMAGES_SUCCESS
} from '../actions/actionTypes'

const initialState = {
 images:[] 
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_IMAGES_SUCCESS:
     return {...state,images:action.payload.images}
    default:
     return state
  }
}

export default reducer;
```

**Now, Please tell me what should i need to do to call that Redux action and 
get Data from the API.I am using React to display data.**

Thanks.

Comment: https://redux.js.org/basics/usagewithreact

Comment: I don't want the documentation link. Can you explain me in shorten?

Comment: @Rajat That is just being lazy

Comment: @Rajat Just sit down and read about Redux and react-redux (connector between react and redux) first. Docs are actually meant for that. SO is meant for situations when you get stuck programmatically doing something beyond docs maybe

Answer (score 3):

In [React redux](https://redux.js.org/basics/usagewithreact) usage page you can use functions like mapStateToProps  and connect to do that

Answer (score 0):

You need a middleware like [Redux-Saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial.html) or [Redux-Thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) to talk with the actions and the global store maintained using Redux.
You may follow this Tutorial: https://redux.js.org/basics/exampletodolist

If you are going with Redux-Thunk, you need to modify your store assign like this:

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

Now, have a container to all the Parent component you have.

```
import { connect  } from 'react-redux';
import App from '../components/App';


export function mapStateToProps(appState) {

  return {
  /* this is where you get your store data through the reducer returned 
  state */
  };
}

export function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
   // make all your action dispatches here
// for ex: getData(payload) => dispatch({type: GETDATA, payload: payload})

  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: i am using redux-thunk. Please explain me How can i call a Redux action from my React frontend and then got the returned state?

Comment: I am seeing "<Provider store={store}>" in the todo example. what is Provider and do i need to use it in react?

Comment: @Rajat Provider infuses the store to your component at root level. This is Composition. I think you need to go through react documents properly. it is well explained there

Comment: Can you please edit your above code, where you used the redux thunk? As you didn't import it and tell how to use it with store. Thanks.

Comment: @Rajat check the first line of code in my answer. middleware is assigned when you create store. which is done at index.js

Comment: One more query please, why you use "mapDispatchToProps" here?, i know mapStateToProps is used to get the intial states.

Comment: @Rajat The name of the function defines its purpose. Please go through the documentation once again. You will be able to understand basics properly.

Comment: can you convert your example to real? As you know i have reducers, actions and store ready. Just need to create one React component then call that action.

Comment: what should i see in that. Thanks.

Comment: @Rajat complete flow. Its a full fledged React Redux app written in Typescript. And keep digging the documentation as well.

Answer (score 0):

As Mustafa said you need to use `mapStateToProps`. Let me explain myself.

What you just done is just the configuration for the main store (there's only one in redux). Now you need to use it in your components, but how ? When you create a Component the content of the `store` will be passed as `props` with the help of `Containers`.

Containers are the way to link your store with your react component.

Said that, you need to install `redux` and `react-redux`. In your code above you have successfully configured the store with the reducers with `redux` library. Now you need `react-redux` to create the Container (which wraps your react component).

Here is an example of how to put this all together: 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RqKyQZ?editors=1010

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But can you please tell me how can i?

Comment: can you please share any refrence with me. But please don't share docs link as they are lengthy to read.

Comment: i will provide an example, give me a minute.

Comment: sure, please do.

Comment: done: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RqKyQZ?editors=1010 If you found it useful like it ^^

Comment: liked, Said to know but i want the api call example and get data.

Comment: That's another story, now you need to use a side-effect library like `redux-thunk` or `redux-observable`.

Comment: I am already setup redux-thunk. As you can see my reducers, stores and actions are ready. Just need to create react component like previously which you created and call the action in that component which will return the state. Brother Please help me to do this. I need this on urgent basis. Thanks for your expensive time.

Comment: will you do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mapStateToProps similar to the code below. Let say your reducer is called test and it is part of a state.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) =>
({
    router: props.router,
    test: state.test
});
```

Then `test` will be used as a property in a React class. Obviously you need to include respective imports for React.